# Is iMac Retina 5K suitable for webdesign?

Tags: website-design, workflow, retina, hardware-recommendation

It is time to retire my old MacBook Pro which served me well for over 5 years, since I dont require portability I am leaning towards buying an iMac 27 with 5K display. I work as a **web designer** and my question is:

- How will a Retina display affect a website design workflow?

I found this interesting [article](http://designm.ag/photoshop-2/pixel-design-issue-photoshop-retina/) but I am interested in your **personal experience** and opinions.

Comment: Personally I am of the opinion of "use something like you expect most users to have" - and that isnt 5k!

Comment: Hi Wojtek, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: What does the article say? Please include a synopsis--that way, your question is still of value if the link breaks at a later time.

Comment: You could go either way. I would use the Retina. You can always test on your old Macbook if you wanted. I use an older Macbook and have no problem using it.

Comment: You might want to read a few more articles on this: https://www.google.com/search?q=is+retina+display+suitable+for+web+designer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: the most urging question is about designing in Photoshop on a document with 72 ppi, retina has twice the amount of pixels. How does that affect designing process?

Answer (score 2):

Retina displays are definitely suitable for web design. There are some things you should understand when using them though.

- Typically, Apple’s “Retina” branding is applied when a display is `220 pixels per inch (PPI)` or higher.
- `220PPI+ displays are common`, especially on mobile devices.
- `One CSS pixel (px) is equal to two display pixels on Retina Macs.` CSS pixels are an abstracted unit of measurement. They relate to the pixels on the display, but they are not always mapped 1:1.
- `One macOS point = one CSS pixel` (except when zoomed etc).
- The 5K iMac’s screen uses the `Display P3` colour space. This might actually be the biggest hurdle when using a new iMac. You’ll have to be careful on how your design tools of choice are set up, and there will be some situations where colours appear oversaturated — currently that happens in Chrome, Sketch and software that doesn’t handle colour management well (I expect these issues to be fixed eventually).

Answer (score 0):

Designs will look small, and you need to work with 144ppi if you would like to get 100% view like in your non-retina screen. With 5k retina you'll get the most smooth design ever, nothing is comparable to it!
I recommend you to use Sketch App for web/app design because it doesn't have the 72ppi issue